# Machine learning com uma linguagem no servidor e outra linguagem no desktop

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, machine-learning

Eu poderia usar Python, para o *machine learning* e C++ para um programa desktop?

O *machine learning* é feito no servidor, correto?

Comment: Essa pergunta está muito ampla. Tudo isso que você está falando depende. Você quer fazer um site? Você quer compartilhar o aprendizado entre as máquinas? Os programas vão ter conexão com a internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, poderia. Pode fazer qualquer coisa em qualquer linguagem. Pro meu gosto acho que faz mais sentido fazer o contrário, mas sei que tem quem discorde. Pra falar a verdade eu faria tudo em C++, a não ser que tenha muita vantagem, já que fazer em uma só linguagem ajuda organizar o projeto. Claro que se há uma equipe com conhecimento amplo em ambas pode ser diferente.

Eu sei que anda uma moda de *machine learning* em Python. Pode haver algum ganho em usá-la na linguagem que já tem bibliotecas adequadas para a tarefa, porém isso ocorre em diversas linguagens. Não posso comparar mas é possível que outras tenham bibliotecas mais avançadas no assunto.

Qualquer código pode colocar onde quiser e necessitar. Se tem um motivo para colocar no servidor, coloque, se pode e é melhor colocar no cliente, faça. Isso vale para qualquer tipo de aplicação. A escolha de ter um servidor ou não, depende da necessidade da aplicação específica, tanto do ponto de vista técnico como até comercial/administrativo.

Se pode fazer sem servidor algum, porque faria um? Se terá um servidor mas a maioria das coisas pode colocar no cliente, porque colocaria no servidor? Que ganhos espera ter? Estas perguntas precisam ser respondidas adequadamente para decidir o que fazer.

Pode ter outros modelos que envolva outras opções.

Na verdade saber se pode ou não fazer isto é a parte fácil.

Comment: Muito bom!
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Sobre fazer ML com Python, creio que o Fernando Masanori tenha um dedo de culpa nisso ;-) Grande divulgador de Python (inclusive para públicos além programadores tradicionais) e também uma ótima pessoa

Comment: Excelente resposta.